# pstricks randomgray text and error messages

Tags: pstricks

On various macs running various installations of texlive, I get one extra line of text in output, something like this:

"tx@Dict begin Rand end{<}randomgraygray tx@Dict begin Rand end{<}gray tx@Dict begin Rand end{<}randomgray" without the braces { }

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\section{Start}
Here we go.
\end{document}
```

I am using Mojave with Texshop and a fresh install of texlive 2019, but I have had this problem on various computers over the years. Doesn't matter if I use xelatex or plain latex

The log file contains messages like this:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

and

```
Runaway argument?
tx@Dict begin Rand Rand Rand end\p@ <\z@ 0\@@ \@@drv \ifx \@@cls \@empty \ETC.
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:667: Parag
raph ended before \c@lor@@rgb was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.667
```

Here is the file list from using \listfile

*File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2004/07/04 v2.00 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   dvips.def    2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97`PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97 `PST-fp' (hv)

---

And here is the full log file if needed:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex 2019.8.13)  22 AUG 2019 09:42
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
)
(/Users/reiss/Library/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2004/07/04 v2.00 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 136.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
)
Package xcolor Info: Color model `cmy' added on input line 972.
Package xcolor Info: Color model`HTML' added on input line 1000.
Package xcolor Info: Color model `HSB' added on input line 1006.
Package xcolor Info: Color model`Gray' added on input line 1012.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count89
\pstFP@xia=\count90
\pstFP@xib=\count91
\pstFP@xfa=\count92
\pstFP@xfb=\count93
\pstFP@rega=\count94
\pstFP@regb=\count95
\pstFP@regs=\count96
\pstFP@times=\count97
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Loading pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@xa=\dimen106
\pgf@xb=\dimen107
\pgf@xc=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@yb=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\c@pgf@counta=\count98
\c@pgf@countb=\count99
\c@pgf@countc=\count100
\c@pgf@countd=\count101
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count102
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count103
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count104
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count105
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen114
\pgffor@skip=\dimen115
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
)
\psLoopIndex=\count106

`PSTricks' v2.97  <2019/05/11> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen116
\pst@dimb=\dimen117
\pst@dimc=\dimen118
\pst@dimd=\dimen119
\pst@dimg=\dimen120
\pst@dimh=\dimen121
\pst@dimm=\dimen122
\pst@dimn=\dimen123
\pst@dimo=\dimen124
\pst@dimp=\dimen125
\pst@hbox=\box28
\pst@ibox=\box29
\pst@boxg=\box30
\pst@cnta=\count107
\pst@cntb=\count108
\pst@cntc=\count109
\pst@cntd=\count110
\pst@cntg=\count111
\pst@cnth=\count112
\pst@cntm=\count113
\pst@cntn=\count114
\pst@cnto=\count115
\pst@cntp=\count116
@zero=\count117
\pst@toks=\toks25
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con)
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng = inserted for \ifdim.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   t
l.662  }

?

/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: LaTeX
 Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   <
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   <
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   <
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   <
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   @temptokena 
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Undef
ined control sequence.
 ...v @temptokena \expandafter {@@col 
                                                  }\csname color@@@cls \exp...
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   <
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   <
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   {
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng = inserted for \ifdim.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Missi
ng number, treated as zero.
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:662: Illeg
al unit of measure (pt inserted).
 
                   t
l.662  }

? 
Runaway argument?
tx@Dict begin Rand Rand Rand end\p@ <\z@ 0@@ @@drv \ifx @@cls @empty \ETC.
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex:667: Parag
raph ended before \c@lor@@rgb was complete.
 
                   \par 
l.667

? 
\psunit=\dimen126
\psxunit=\dimen127
\psyunit=\dimen128
\pst@C@@rType=\count118
\pslinewidth=\dimen129
\psk@startLW=\dimen130
\psk@endLW=\dimen131
\pst@customdefs=\toks26
\pslinearc=\dimen132
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen133
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen134
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen135
\everypsbox=\toks27
\psframesep=\dimen136
\pslabelsep=\dimen137
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen138
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen139
\pst@shift=\dimen140
)
File: pstricks.tex 2019/05/11 v2.97 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
File: pst-fp.tex 2019/05/11 v2.97`PST-fp' (hv)
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
 [1

] (./test.aux)

*File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX,
 and LuaTeX
shellesc.sty    2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
  xcolor.sty    2004/07/04 v2.00 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   dvips.def    2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97`PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2019/05/11 v2.97 `PST-fp' (hv)

---

)
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

#### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 662 (\begingroup)

#### bottom level

(\end occurred when \ifx on line 662 was incomplete) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7280 strings out of 492610
 134550 string characters out of 6129074
 192330 words of memory out of 5000000
 11171 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4245 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 36i,5n,41p,395b,1424s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 920 bytes).

Comment: show the complete log-file from your minimal example.

Comment: there is something wrong with your TeX installtion. Put `\listfiles` as first line into your document and show the file list, which is at the end of your log file.

Comment: This problem occurs using texlive 2017, 2018 and 2019 on my system, using either latex or xelatex. (The error message in the output changes slightly). Everything is fine with texlive 2015 on the same system.

Answer (score 2):

A fresh reinstallation via MacTeX fixed the problem, not only for texlive 2019, but also for the older installations.